# Magento 1.9 Product View Count on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am displaying product view count on detail page using **ajax call** on **page load** but it is taking a lot of time. I am sharing my code below.

```
$jsonArray = array();
    //Views count 
    $count = 0;
    $fromDate = '2016-03-16';
    $toDate   = now();
    $viewedProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount($fromDate,$toDate);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($viewedProducts as $product) {
        if($product->getData('entity_id')==$productId)
        {
            $count = $product->getData('views');
        }
    }
    echo $count;
```

Is there any optimized ways of getting current product view count?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this to multiple products? If so, you could filter your collection by doing this:

```
$productsIds = [1, 2, 3];
$viewedProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', ['in' => $productIds])
        ->addAttributeToSelect('views');
```

Now you can loop the viewed products and get the views for each of them

Comment: I need to get the count of one product only not for multiple products. Does this code will get only the current product view count?